# AngularJS Select: Initial selection not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I cannot figure out why the initial selection is not working in this code. Everything else is just fine. The options are all there, etc...

```
<select id="userEmail" class="form-control"
                            data-ng-init="userSelection = users[0]"
                            data-ng-model="userSelection"
                            data-ng-options="user.email for user in users">
                        </select>
```

Also the variant with `userSelection = userSelection || users[0]` does not work.

Comment: Would help if you replicate this in a plunkr or fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Would make this just a comment, but can't yet.

Your code should work. I pretty copied it into [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQcSGPlMLCQ3IGSukoRl) and it works just fine.

I guess just make sure you have all your controllers and whatnots set up correctly.

```
<select id="userEmail" class="form-control"
    data-ng-init="userSelection = users[5]"
    data-ng-model="userSelection"
    data-ng-options="user.email for user in users">
</select>
<hr>
{{ userSelection }}
```

Comment: This is really strange... I double-checked everything again. Should be fine. I mean, I am getting the users in the drop down menu anyway, so there should be no problem while retrieving them from the controller. It is just the fact, that I cannot make a preselection :/

Comment: This answer should not be a comment ;)